# printing a list of persons with more than one home, each home with more than one phone number

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a class Person which can have several Homes, each one with one or many Phone numbers.

I have defined the classes, but now i am trying to create a view wich list every person, with all its homes and all the phone numbers for each home address... something like:

```
john smith
123 fake str
  305-99-8877
  305-99-8876
321 oak road
  444-98-7654

peter guy
453 north ave...
```

so far i have something like this:

(on my views.py)

```
def ViewAll(request):
  people = Person.objects.all()
  render_to_response('viewall.html', {'people': people})
```

(and on my template)

```
{% for guy in people %} 
  {{ guy.name }}
  {% if person.home_address_set.all %}
    {{ home_address }}

    {% for ?????? in ???? %}
      #print phone numbers in each home
    {% endfor %}

  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

any idea of how to write the for I'm missing? of course, if there is another way (a better more elegant or efficient way) of doing what I need, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have what appears to be three nested collections: Person, Home, Phone Number.

Step 1 - How would you write this in a view function?

```
for p in Person.objects.all():
    print "person", p
    for h in p.home_address_set.all():
         print " home", h
         for ph in h.phone_set.all():
             print "  phone", ph
```

Don't omit this step.  If you can't make it work in a view function, your model is wrong.  Take the time to get this part right.

Step 2 - Convert this into template syntax.

```
{% for p on people %}
    {% for h in p.home_address_set.all %}
        {% fpr ph in h.phone_set.all %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The results should be the same as your view function.